# Ubuntu 18.04 Installing nvidia 390 driver whipped login gear and wayland

Tags: nvidia, xorg, login-screen, wayland

After having set nvdia 390 display driver in software&updates the gear icon at login is missing so I can no more choose between xorg and wayland.
Setting back to nouveau display driver doesn't change anything, the gear remains missing.

Please, how could I make the gear to reappear ?

(Obviously it is xorg now, as scale factor cannot be changed independently for multiple displays, but what should be the normal way to get the display mode?)